Intermittent emails not making it to a Library
I am running the advanced setup for receiving incoming emails on my SharePoint Subscription Edition On Premise Farm. I have Microsoft SharePoint Foundation jobs looking every minute on 3 boxes. The delivery works about 70% of the time, but some of the emails are getting delayed and then lost. Why one makes it over and another with the same attachment does not is baffling. I can even take an email I already sent (that failed to write to the library) and forward it to the same library, and it might succeed. Has anyone experienced this in SP 2019 or SE? Our Exchange admin shows these messages as Delivered. I cannot post the headers for specific reasons, but I see nothing that stands out between delivered items or failed ones.

It may be helpful to check the SharePoint logs for any errors or warnings related to incoming email.

Yes. Thank you. We're working on a possible solution. If I get this repaired, I will post an answer.

I was attempting to build in redundancy and that was the issue. Once I went with a single Exchange box, it works.

Create a Foreign connector on 1 exchange server.
Create a new drop folder on the exchange server.
Point to the drop folder in Central Admin.
This depends on your environment, but you may need to enable a rule
and connector on M365 exchange admin center.

Configure incoming email for a SharePoint Server Farm - Advanced Scenario
